# How do I use the checkbox type of input in PHP correctly

Tags: php, html, forms

I want the code below to show all the selected checkboxes and to have a limit of 2 checkboxes ticked.

Input

```
<form method="post" action="Outputofinfo.php">
   <b style="font-size:19px ; color: #7a1ac4; font: Arial,tahoma,sans-serif; ">Favourite Movie Genre:</b><br>
   
    <input type="checkbox" name="mg" value="Romance">
 <label for="mg1"> Romance</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mg" value="Comedy">
 <label for="mg2"> Comedy</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mg" value="Horror">
 <label for="mg3"> Horror</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mg" value="Action">
 <label for="mg4"> Action</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mg" value="Fiction">
 <label for="mg5"> Fiction</label><br>

 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

output

```
$fmg = $_POST['mg'];
<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'>
    <b>Favourite Movie Genre:</b>
    <?php echo $fmg; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `name="mg[]"` then `$_POST["mg"]` will be an array. Limiting the number of checked boxes will have to be done with JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Adding `[]` to the end of `name` attribute like `name=mg[]` makes it send an array of values to the server. You can simply access the array on the server-side. For example you can access first element of it like: `$_POST['mg'][0]`.
By using a `foreach` you can access all of the selected checkboxes.
Or you can use something like this:

```
$fmg = implode(", ", $_POST['mg']);
```

and show `$fmg` to the user as you want.
Your code will be:

```
<form method="post" action="Outputofinfo.php">
   <b style="font-size:19px ; color: #7a1ac4; font: Arial,tahoma,sans-serif; ">Favourite Movie Genre:</b><br>
   
    <input type="checkbox" name="mg[]" value="Romance">
 <label for="mg1"> Romance</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mg[]" value="Comedy">
 <label for="mg2"> Comedy</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mg[]" value="Horror">
 <label for="mg3"> Horror</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mg[]" value="Action">
 <label for="mg4"> Action</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mg[]" value="Fiction">
 <label for="mg5"> Fiction</label><br>

 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

output:

```
$fmg = implode(",",$_POST['mg']);
<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'>
    <b>Favourite Movie Genre:</b>
    <?php echo $fmg; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please repeat my code and add what you said @Sohrab

Comment: Check it now please